# unable to deploy war app -springboot- in tomcat

Tags: tomcat

this application was work fine before I changed it from jar to war, I am trying to deploy war application -springBoot- in tomcat, getting

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No ConfigurationProperties annotation found

```
    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JmsTemplateProperties:

    5 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.4
    6 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jul 6 2016 08:43:30 UTC
    6 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.4.0
    7 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 7
    7 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            6.1
    7 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
    7 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Nazar\Softwares\jdk1.8.0_40\jre
    8 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_40-b26
    8 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
    8 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\TaaS\t1
    8 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\TaaS\t1
    9 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
    9 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\TaaS\t1\conf\logging.properties
    .011 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
    .012 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\TaaS\t1
    .014 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\TaaS\t1
    .015 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\TaaS\t1\temp
    .018 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.8 using APR version 1.5.2.
    .019 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
    .021 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
    .705 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016)
    .865 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8091"]
    .944 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    .948 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
    .952 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
    .954 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1376 ms
    .984 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Application
    .985 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.4
    02-Sep-2016 05:01:16.022 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\TaaS\t1\webapps\Application.war
    02-Sep-2016 05:01:33.797 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
    02-Sep-2016 05:01:33.973 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.log Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration$JerseyWebApplicationInitializer@4dc2ccf6, com.test.package.Application@2c32442e]
    02-Sep-2016 05:01:48.161 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
     org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Application].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Application]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:724)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No ConfigurationProperties annotation found on  'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JmsTemplateProperties'.
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationPropertiesImportSelector$ConfigurationPropertiesBeanRegistrar.registerBeanDefinition(EnableConfigurationPropertiesImportSelector.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationPropertiesImportSelector$ConfigurationPropertiesBeanRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(EnableConfigurationPropertiesImportSelector.java:82)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:352)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:333)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:149)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:129)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:152)
        ... 10 more

    02-Sep-2016 05:01:48.184 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive C:\Users\testuser\Desktop\TaaS\t1\webapps\Application.war
     java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Application].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/Application]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:700)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)


        @SpringBootApplication
    @ComponentScan
    @EnableDiscoveryClient
    @EnableContentCommons
    public class Application  extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
        @Override
        protected SpringApplicationBuilder     configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
            return application.sources(Application.class);
        }
```

Comment: My application doent have any jms, and the pom.xml and main app are fine, I tested them using small app

Comment: main class at the end of the log

Comment: getting the following exception:   Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE.

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy as traditional WAR file, you must have something like these:

```
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(BootApplication.class);
    }

}
```

and

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class BootApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(BootApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

`gradle.build`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.4.0.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'
apply plugin: 'war'


war {
    baseName = 'boot'
    version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
}
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}


eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers 'org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8'
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Do Nhu Vy for your quick response, I have it .. please check the end of the log, this is my first time to use stackoverflow, not yet familiar with formating ;)

Comment: @nnaz I noticed you tried editing this answer to completely change it into another question. Edits don't work like that. You edit an answer to improve the quality of the answer. If you still have questions you can edit your own question to include new information or just open a new question entirely.

Comment: Sure leigero, but its the same issue, just the log not clear, thats why I made update, but ext time I will open new question ;)

Comment: @leigero I am not able to open new question ;(

Comment: @nnaz if this is related to the same issue you can just update your current question to include the new information.